# How can we measure the performance of azure search suggest API for 100 concurrent users?

Tags: unit-testing, autocomplete, azure-cognitive-search, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I have implemented autosuggestion feature in my application and I am using azure search suggest service for providing suggestion. It's working fine for me but I am not sure what will be the impact after making it live when around 100 users will use my application concurrently. Currently I am thinking to use standard(S1) pricing tier.

Is there anyway so that I can test load for 100 users for newly added feature i.e. autocomplete?

Comment: I am waiting for response if this is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-traffic-analytics to see how you can add insturmentation for the ***Search traffic analytics*** blade to consume. What I would advise is starting at Basic and build a test harness like a console app, that could simulate your 100 concurrent users. There are load test features built into Azure Dev Ops also, you can check out those options at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops. You can then review the data captured in the ***Search traffic analytics*** blade to guestimate if Basic will be enough for 100 concurrent users or whether not you need to move up to a Standard teir.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for sharing these details. But may I know what is expected/standard response time for suggestions from azure search for 5, 50 and 100 concurrent users for basic and standard pricing tiers?

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have any metrics on response times. I would advise reviewing the [service metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity) and follow these [tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-sku-tier#tips-for-tier-evaluation) in order to come up with an efficient indexing strategy.